# What is Windows Access?

Tags: networking, system, desktop, lan, wan

At my work, we have an Desktop ERP system that uses a tool called windows access (it is not the database), this tool allow the user to query the ERP System without having it installed on the desktop machine, as long as the server has a process running.

My question: how do that work ? is the user interface streamed through network ? and the actions(filling forms, press buttons and etc..) stramed back ? and how do i do that ?

it work through WAN and through LAN.

thanks and sorry for bad english.

Comment: This is clearly not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like RDP. check it out at here [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol).

Comment: Could also be a java webstart thingy. Comes out the same.